# Drools: Find if a map contains a partial key and assign it to a a variable

Tags: java, drools

I have a **topic object** which contains a **map of messages**. The keys are usernames and the values are the messages. 
There's a single user with a name that always starts with **User** but ends with a substring that is always changing.

I know that there is only one user corresponding to the pattern **UserXXX**.

My goal is to get this message's key, based on the partial key **User**.

I've tried using the code below, using the `matches` operator and feeding it the pattern regex.
I've also tried extracting the key using known user names:
`$key: String(this in ("User001","User002","User003")) from $keys`

But none of my attempts worked.

```java
rule "Find messages by UserXXX"
  when
    topic: Topic()

    $keys: List() from topic.get("messages").keySet()
    $key: String(this matches "User.*") from $keys
  then
    System.out.println("The full username is " + $key); 
end
```

Given a map:

```
{
  "User001": "Message",
  "Jasper": "Message",
  "Micks": "Message"
}
```

I expect to get the key `User001`into a variable `$key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested another way and it returned the desired result:

```java
rule "Find messages by UserXXX"
  when
    topic: Topic()

    $messagesMap: HashMap() from topic.get("messages")
    $messageEntry: Entry($userKey : key matches "User.*") from $messagesMap.entrySet()

  then
    System.out.println("The full username is " + $userKey); 
end
```

In this attempt I filter the map entries to get the one that has a key matching my pattern.